# Running program returns -1.#QNAN0

Tags: c, file-io

Whilst using an input file to calculate a sum, the file contains two columns of numbers as well as an integer director above the first column, I came upon an error that said,  when i created the sum of the second column of numbers, conductivity, it is not a number, and returns `-1.#QNAN0`, I tried changing variable names and changing order, which I know has nothing to do with this issue. Also when I run the program, the conductivity values are shown on the screen, but for some reason cannot be summed up.

```
/* Main Function */
int main(void) {
    /* Declare and initialize Variables */
    double temp, conduc, tempsqrd, temptconduc, sumtemp, sumconduc;
    double sumtempsqrd, sumtemptconduc, slope, yint;
    int i, ndata;
    FILE *therm, *out;

    /* Open Files */
    therm = fopen(inputfile, "r");
    out = fopen(outputfile, "w");

    /* print output headings */
    printf("******************************************");
    printf("\n   TEMPERATURE vs THERMAL CONDUCTIVITY"
           "\n           by Tyrus Sonneborn"
           "\n\nTemp    Conduct    Temp Sqrd    Temp*Conduct");
    fprintf(out, "******************************************");
    fprintf(out, "\n    TEMPERATURE vs THERMAL CONDUCTIVITY"
                 "\n           by Tyrus Sonneborn"
                 "\n\nTemp    Conduct    Temp Sqrd    Temp*Conduct");   

    /* Verify input file and read control number */
    if (therm == NULL) {
        printf("\n\n\n\n   ERROR OPENING INPUT FILE.");
        printf("\n\n   PROGRAM TERMINATED.\n\n\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        /* Read control number */
        fscanf(therm, "%i", &ndata);

        /* Compute the conductivity data and sums. */
        for (i = 1; i <= ndata; i++) {
            fscanf(therm, "%lf %lf", &temp, &conduc);
            sumconduc = conduc + sumconduc;
            tempsqrd = pow(temp, 2);
            temptconduc = temp * conduc;
            sumtemp = temp + sumtemp;
            sumtempsqrd = sumtempsqrd;
            sumtemptconduc = sumtemptconduc;
            printf("\n %3f     %4.0f       %6.0f       %6.0f",
                   temp, conduc, tempsqrd, temptconduc);
            fprintf(out, "\n %3f     %5.1f       %6.0f      %6.0f",
                    temp, conduc, tempsqrd, temptconduc);
        }
    }
    /* computing the slope and y intercept */
    slope = (sumtemp * sumconduc - ndata * sumtemptconduc) / (pow(sumtemp, 2) - ndata * (pow(sumtemp, 2)));
    yint = (sumconduc - slope * sumtemp) / ndata;
    printf("\n\n%10f, %10f, %10f, %10f",
           sumtemp, sumconduc, sumtempsqrd, sumtemptconduc);
    fprintf(out, "\n\n%10f, %10f, %10f, %10f",
            sumtemp, sumconduc, sumtempsqrd, sumtemptconduc);
```

Comment: Have you run a debugger?

Comment: Recommend verifying `fscanf()` results area as expected --> `if (fscanf(therm,"%lf %lf",&temp,&conduc) != 2) {return puts("error"); } printf("%e %e\n", temp,conduc);`

Comment: BTW: `#include <math.h>` missing.

Comment: Step through the code. Find out where the NaN comes from. My guess is it's coming from the `pow` function.

Comment: `double sumconduc; /*...*/ sumconduc = conduc + sumconduc;` Where is `sumconduc` initialized?

Comment: All of the functions are creating the correct sums except for the sumconduc function.

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, you use `sumconduc` uninitialized:

```
sumconduc = conduc + sumconduc;
```

You should initialize it to `0`.  The same holds for `sumtemp`, `sumtempsqrd`, and `sumtemptconduc`.

Compiling with warnings enabled such as by `gcc -Wall -Wextra` would have diagnosed such silly mistakes.